# Does a low-orbit communication network drive a sustainable launch market?

Tags: spacex, communication-satellite

With SpaceX recent announcement of a huge satellite network in low earth orbit, I was wondering if such a network would motivate a sustainable large-scale launch capacity, i.e. a increase of scale of production and usage of launchers.

Obviously, one needs quite a lot of rockets to put 4k satellites into orbit, but for how long?

1. Is further miniaturization of these ku-band communication satellites possible, or do factors like frequency (antennas) or power supply limit this?
2. Is there any reliable estimate about the number of launches needed to maintain the network?
3. Is the high number of satellites a necessity (i.e. motivated by the geometry of the network) or might it be overcome by a later generation of satellites?

Comment: The announcement isn't that recent. SpaceX filed a request with the FCC for a test system about 18 months ago. What's recent is the FCC filing for the operational system.